# Bootstrap form horizontal: align two inputs next to each other

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am trying to figure out how to align two inputs (like zip and city) parallel side by side in Bootstrap using `form-horizontal`. I tried using the `div.row` wrapper with `spanX` classes combined with `input-block-level`.

Alternatively, I attempted to leave out the `div.row` but giving the inputs the `spanX` classes directly.

The problem is, that the width of the inputs differs. Maybe this is a bug, but at a certain viewport (requires `bootstrap-responsive.css`) it works properly — but not with a large viewport and sometimes horizontal scrollbars appear.

Shouldn't rhe responsive stylesheet of Bootstrap adapt the sizes? Wrapping the whole code in a `div.container` makes it even worse.

Maybe you can even show me some complete different solutions?

I prepared a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aKnzS/) and some screenshots for you. You can find the size of the window and the size of the viewport (in square brackets) in the title. Click the images for full size.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember that `spanX` classes are implemented with percentages, so sometimes the edges will not align properly when putting multiple input areas in same row. So when you use a `span12` class, the members of that `div` might get warped.

The labels are another concern in this multiple input per line scenario. They take 160px, so they are not compatible with `span12` input areas. They are best for one input per line and `span1-span10`.

```
<form class="container-fluid">
    <div class="control-group">

        <div class="controls row-fluid">
            <input type="text" class="span11" placeholder="Street" />
        </div>

        <div class="controls controls-row row-fluid">
            <input type="text" class="span4" placeholder="Zip" />
            <input type="text" class="span7" placeholder="City" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have added two more classes on your 2nd row, `controls-row` and `row-fluid` - first one aligns the rows together while the other makes the length fluid.

**A better design decision will be to get rid of the labels - the placeholders already do their job - in case of multiple input areas on same row. That way you can use the entire 11 columns.**

The horizontal scroll bar will appear sometimes due to the 12 column structure, so get rid of it by setting "overflow-x:hidden" right on the body element.

Answer (score 0):

Because which style you are changing is working only for mobile screen devices. If you use the above code;

```
.input-block-level{
    width:60%;

}
```

you'll only find the **zip** and **country** inputs aligned only on mobile viewport example-320px/480px and above it wouldn't work. So you have to add any style like this to add in other mediaqueries also like 768px or whatever you want.
Your code will work at any cost either style it via `class` method or via `input[type="text"]` method, only thing they should be in the exact mediaqueries.

Comment: `.input-block-level` is made for a 100% width. And I want the `input` to have that width. Sad to say that your answer does not help :(